# Specify xAxis values with columnRange chart in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart, trying to make a chart that shows high and low values for the number of people occupying various rooms.  So I have a data like this:

```
[[roomName, low, high], [roomName, low, high] ...]
```

For example:

```
["XRay", 12, 45], ["Waiting Room", 8, 22], ["Admitting", 22, 56]]
```

What I want to have happen is for the x Axis to use the room names as the values on the category axis.  But I can't see to get this to happen.  It uses them as the names of the points instead.

If I am just doing a column chart, I can set x and y properties for the points:

```
[x:"XRay", y:12], [x:"Waiting Room", y:8], [x:"Admitting", y:56]]
```

But I don't know how I can do this with column ranges.

I can of course manually parse the data and set the categories of the xAxis myself, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why do you want it, using categories is the best way.

Comment: Without categories you have to parse it inside xAxis labels' formatter. So use categories.

Comment: It is possible to add mock-up / image how it should look like as a result?

Comment: The reason I wanted to do it without parsing the data and setting the categories axis is that I have a single control that is rendering data returned from a REST service.  Ideally I could just do a single setData command and have it always do the correct thing.  If I use the setCategories approach, I have to check the result and then add categories by hand if the result set contains them.  But I guess that is what I need to do.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in two ways, as suggested categories, or using label formatter, both are here: http://jsbin.com/oyudan/17/edit

Formats:

```
[ {x: 'string' } ... ]
```

are not proper.